# Bazel: BUILD fragments need to differ based on the target operating system

Tags: bazel

I have something like this in a BUILD file. I am un/commenting lines based on the operating system. Is there a graceful way to do this?

```
    # Ubuntu
    #shared_libraries = [
    #    "libboost_atomic.so"
    #],
    # OSX
    shared_libraries = [
        "libboost_atomic.dylib"
    ],
```

Comment: I haven't tried this however the [bazel-build/rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) uses this kind of approach by wrapping the native binary and querying its's [Node JS OS](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) API.

[OS Name Function](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/internal/common/os_name.bzl)

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a real feature. Thanks @jnelson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this however the [bazel-build/rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) uses this kind of approach by wrapping the native binary and querying its's [Node JS OS](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) API.

[OS Name Function](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/internal/common/os_name.bzl)(uses context given from user running `node.exe`)

---

### UPDATE

**Check here**

[Setting up a C++ Toolchain](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html#configuring-the-c-toolchain)

This seems to be what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, I've been to that bramble patch of a page. I guess this is why nobody uses Bazel for C projects. If I ever figure this out I'll post something on Medium about it.

Comment: Thank you but that is insanity. The debugger on OSX doesn't pick up the debug libraries anyway (have to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) whereas Linux (Ubuntu) doesn't have this problem. So, coding on OSX is a joke. Luckily I can use Linux only.